# In navigation, what's the difference between bearing, heading, direction, and course?

Tags: single-word-requests, differences, nouns, terminology

Specifically, in real-world use, I would think that "course" and "heading" tend to imply a vector of movement, while "bearing" and "direction" might refer only to which way one is facing.

I am looking for two words to correctly assign to these physical components of a vehicle. I suppose I may be looking for military, or naval terminology.

For example, if you were in a submarine, being buffeted by currents, so your vessel was being pushed sideways, how would you correctly say, "we are being pushed east but we are facing north?" Would it be correct to say "we are bearing 0°, but our heading is 270°?" It doesn't *sound* correct.

**Edit**

As I note in a comment below: when I clumsily wrote that I was "looking for two words to correctly assign to these physical components of a vehicle," what I meant was, single-word attributes to distinguish between the direction a vehicle was facing, and the actual direction the vehicle was moving in, voluntarily or not.

Comment: Title suggests a localized vocabulary!

Answer (score 4):

**Bearing** is regularly defined as the direction (relative to true north) in which your destination lies. If you could go in a straight line to your destination, this would be the most direct way of getting there.

You also have **relative bearing**, where the front of the vehicle is considered "north"; you'll see this when pilots claim, for example, that something is "at your 3 o'clock"; in naval terminology, port (left) and starboard (right) are always relative to the bow (front of the vessel).

**Heading** is the direction your face/nose/front/bow is currently pointing at (relative to true north), assuming default movement by your vehicle's impulse mechanism is forward. If there are no obstacles between you and your destination, and nothing aside from your vehicle's own impulse mechanism is moving it, heading should always be equal to bearing.

**Course** describes the entire planned route to get to your destination. A course correction implies that your planned route encountered an obstacle, and that you have to correct that plan.

As an example, let's assume a car is the vehicle, and it's navigating in a standard grid-like street structure. If you're at point (0, 0) with your car facing north and your destination is at (3, 3), your course would be "Three blocks north, then three blocks east". Your bearing at the start of your journey would be north-east, and your heading would be north, since that's the way your car is facing.

After you travel three blocks north, you're stopped at a red light. You should plan to turn right, to change your heading to east, since your bearing is now east. Your remaining course is "3 blocks east".

In aviation, where winds can and often will push you off-course, heading is rarely equal to bearing when the total travel distance is large. This makes for frequent course corrections to account for wind.

In my opinion, **direction** is the most basic term of all, and describes a directed vector between two points.

For your example, it seems like the proper phrasing would be "We are heading north, but we're being pushed off-course eastwards."

Comment: Thanks — the distinction between bearing, heading, and course makes sense to me, although your definition of heading does not agree with jwpat7's. When I clumsily wrote that I was "looking for two words to correctly assign to these physical components of a vehicle," what I meant was, single-word attributes to distinguish between the direction a vehicle was facing, and the actual direction the vehicle was moving in, voluntarily or not. I think "orientation" might work for the former, but I'm not sure which, if any, of the words I listed could really be applied to non-voluntary motion.

Comment: There is almost always at least the Earth itself in the way. So even without obstacles, wind, and the like, heading and bearing differ on the shortest path, unless you're going directly up or tunneling through the Earth.

Comment: Heading is direction you are currently _facing_, which may _not_ correspond the direction you are navigating in presence of currents (at sea) or wind (in the air).

Comment: this was reposted in Aviation.SE and answered (correctly): http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/bearing-vs-course-vs-direction-vs-heading-vs-track

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Jim In what way?

Comment: @Jim I noticed that the cardinal direction in the example was wrong, so I submitted an edit to fix it. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: *"assuming default movement by your vehicle's impulse mechanism is forward"* -- Could you clarify? Is that referring to vehicles that go more vertically than horizontally, like diving bells?

Comment: I meant that cars, boats and planes have impulse mechanisms (engines) that more often than not move you in the direction that their front is pointing. If you had a car that allowed both front wheels and rear wheels to be turned by the steering wheel, your car may be facing forwards, but your heading could be anything from forward-left to forward right (great for parallel parking).

Answer (score 3):

*Bearing* is the direction to an external object, which is obviously an essential part of navigation. So "your bearing is 180 degrees" is not meaningful; "your bearing is 180 degrees from the lighthouse" is helpful (sometimes expressed as "0 degrees to the lighthouse", but that's another question).

*Heading* is what you are looking for to express the direction you are facing (I think Wikipedia's explanation is confusing; yes, it is expressed as an angle, but only when necessary to reduce it to numbers: 'heading due west' is perfectly normal.)

There is no single word to express the direction you are actually travelling in, probably because there are so many components (wind, leeway, current, pilot error...).  *Course made good* or *track over ground* are probably closest.

Comment: Thanks, great clarification! The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_%28navigation%29) jwpat7 links to also says of aircraft that "due to wind forces, the direction of movement of the aircraft, or track, is not the same as the heading. The nose of the aircraft may be pointing due west… but a strong northerly wind will change its track south of west" which is much like my submarine example, and suggests that _track_ alone may be the other word I want, meaning direction-craft-is-actually-going. It implies to me observed motion.

Answer (score 1):

The notion that "heading tends to imply a vector of movement" is incorrect; as noted in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_%28navigation%29), "Heading is the angle of the vessel, aircraft or vehicle to an object (e.g. true north)", and angles do not require or imply motion of an object.

Also as noted in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_%28navigation%29), "In navigation, a vehicle's course is the angle that the intended path of the vehicle makes with a fixed reference object (typically true north)", and "The *track* or *course over ground*, is the actual path followed by the vessel" [italics added] and "The angle between heading and track is known as the drift angle or crab angle".

With that terminology understood, now consider "words to correctly assign to these physical components of a vehicle".  The appropriate terms depend on kind of vehicle, but for an aircraft typically are *[roll, pitch,  and yaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll,_pitch,_and_yaw)*.

Answer (score 0):

*

"being buffeted by currents...your vessel was being pushed sideways, how would you correctly say, "we are being pushed east but we are facing north?"...

*A vessel or vehicle points where it points, that is the heading.  It's course is the actual line it travels.  So if your boat is facing north (navigational 0 degrees) and the currents are easterly (moving TO the east) thus pushing you off-track to the eastside of your intended track, you have to compensate for the current.  This is done by steering your bow slightly into the oncoming current, in this case to port or slightly west of north.  In a current of approximately 2 knots, you might have to compensate -10 degrees off bearing (your destination), say heading 350 degrees, so that your Course can remain due north at 0 degrees, where your "bearing" lies.
That 10 degrees is a "drift" or "crab" angle, named that since crabs walk sideways, kind of like your ship is doing by heading differently from your true course/bearing.

Answer (score -2):

*Heading* is where you want to go. *Bearing* is the direction you are going.